# Intersection of collection of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Working through a proof and the following was given without any explanation:

> Let X be a set with a topology T . Let O be a collection of open sets of X such that for each open set U ⊂ X and each x ∈ U, there exists a $U_{x} ⊂ U $with $x ∈ U_{x}$ and $U_{x} ∈ O.$ Then O is a basis for T .

In proving that O is a basis, the proof says that For $U_{1}, U_{2} \in O$ such that $x \in U_{1} \cap U_{2}$ and $U_{1}, U_{2}$ open in X, we **know** that there exists $U_{3}$. Intuitively, this makes sense to me, but I can't find any proof of this, even though it's referenced in many places. Any help?

Comment: You write $U_x \subset U$ and also $U_x \in U$. Can you fix your statement? It is difficult to understand what you are giving us and what you are asking for.

Comment: Done! I meant it to be \in

Comment: Also, what definition of basis does your textbook give? There is more than one way to define a basis for a topology, though they're pretty much equivalent. It would help to know this definition.

Comment: The definition is: for all x in X, there is a basis element B such that $x \in B$, and that if x belongs to the intersection of two basis elements, there exists a third basis element in which x is contained. The Munkres book is what I'm using.

Comment: And is there a second condition given in that definition? It seems that that is not the full definition.

Comment: Yes, I pressed enter accidentally

Comment: We know that the there is a $U_3$ with what property?  If you just let an $U_3 = U_1$ or any other $U_k \in O$ we know it exists because $O$ isn't empty.  So that is a pointless statement.  The real is wwe know there there is a $U_3$ that .... has some property.  What property.  I assume so that $x \in U_3$ which we know because "O is characterized such that for all x in O, there is a Ux∈U with x∈Ux∈U"

Comment: Well the proper definition is: If x belongs to the intersection of two basis elements ($x \in B_{1} \cap B_{2}$) then there exists $B_{3}$ such that $B_{3} \subset B_{1} \cap B_{2}$

Comment: "O is characterized such that for all x in O, there is a $U_x∈U$"  What the heck is $U$? That was never defined or introduced in any way. Did you mean $U_x \in O$?  So that for all sets $x \in O$ that there is another set $y \in O$ so that $x \in y$?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I should be more clear. U is an open set of X. I'll fix the problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open, ,then $U_1 \cap U_2$ is open by the definition of a topology (finite intersections are open.)

Hence, as soon as $x \in U_1 \cap U_2$, there already exists some $U_x \subset U_1 \cap U_2$ by the last highlighted sentence, so in particular, there is a $U_3 \subset U_1 \cap U_2$ that contains $x$.

Comment: ...I'm embarrassed I didn't catch that. Finals season folks, it takes away brain cells! Thank you friend.

Comment: no problem. Good luck studying for finals